# File field tag within relationship tag not working

Tags: relationships, ee2-upgrades, files

Recently, I upgraded an EE2 website to EE5.1.2. Before EE upgrade, I imported Playa into Relationships field. Everything working perfectly except file tag within relationship isn't outputting correct file/image path. Code example is as below:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="CHANNEL_NAME" limit="1" disable="member_data|pagination" status="open" require_entry="yes"}
{relationship_field}
<img src="{relationship_field:thumb_image}" alt="{relationship_field:title}" />
{/relationship_field}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

It might work nicely but not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified your path settings have not changed during the upgrade?

What does the code output?

Should your `alt="{title}"` actually be `alt="{relationship_field:title}"`

Comment: Thanks Tim, actually problem is with field field tag `{relationship_field:thumb_image}` which isn't working. I corrected `alt` in question.

Comment: So it does output the alt text?
I'd first check if the file exists, then if the server paths are correct for the upload  folder.
Is the image an uploaded image or an image manipulation of an uploaded image? You could also go into the database and see how it's stored there to be sure